# Breadcrumb not showing in yii1 when Bootstrap files are included

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have a yii1 application working. It currently includes a breadcrumb.

I am changing the current design so it will use Bootstrap but, when I include bootstrap stylesheets and javascript files the breadcrumb disappears.

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- blueprint CSS framework -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/admin/css/style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title><?php echo CHtml::encode($this->pageTitle); ?></title>

        <!--[if IE 6]>
<script src="js/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      DD_belatedPNG.fix('img,div,ul,li,li a,a,input,p,blockquote,span,h1,h2,h3');
</script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 9)]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
    <link href="css/ieonly.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->


    <style>
    @media all
    {
#footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:43px;
   width:100%;
}
}

.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
  
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mega-dropdown {
  position: static !important;
  width: 100%;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

.open .dropdown-toggle:after {
    border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
    border-left: 17px solid transparent;
    border-right: 17px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    left: 163px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -21px;
    z-index: 1500;
}

.open .dropdown-toggle span:after {
    border-bottom: 17px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 19px solid transparent;
    border-right: 19px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    left: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -41px;
    z-index: 8;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #999;
  white-space: normal;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:hover,
.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
  color: #428bca;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu form {
  margin: 3px 20px;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #6bc0eb !important;
    border-color: #6bc0eb !important;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #fff !important;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
    color: #fff !important;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #6bc0eb !important;
}
.glyphicon
{
 
 display:none;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #6bc0eb !important;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #6bc0eb !important;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse, .navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
    border-color: #6bc0eb;
}

</style>
<style>
@media all
{
 .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu
 {
  background-color:#fff !important;
 }
}
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait)
   {

   .footertext
   {
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    /* width: 220px; */
    width: 179px;
    text-align: justify !important;
    width: 290px;
    /* word-break: break-all; */
    /* word-break: keep-all; */
   margin: 0px !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    font-weight: 800 !important;
}

}

@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 533px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.4)
  and (orientation: portrait)
   {


.footertext
   {
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    /* width: 220px; */
    width: 179px;
    text-align: justify !important;
    width: 290px;
    /* word-break: break-all; */
    /* word-break: keep-all; */
   margin: 0px !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    font-weight: 800 !important;
}
   }
</style>
<style>
.scrollToTop{
 width:100px; 
 height:130px;
 padding:10px; 
 text-align:center; 
 background: whiteSmoke;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #444;
 text-decoration: none;
 position:fixed;
 top:75px;
 right:-34px;
 display:none;
 background: url('<?php echo Yii::app()->request->getBaseUrl(true); ?>/images/arrowup.png') no-repeat 0px 20px;
}
.scrollToTop:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}

</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
   $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
  } else {
   $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
  }
 });
 
 //Click event to scroll to top
 $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
  return false;
 });
 
});






</script>


</head>

<body>







 <?php if($_SESSION['admin_id']) {  ?>

  


<div class="container">

<div class="masthead">
<a  href="<?php echo $this->createUrl("admin/index"); ?>"><img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/images/admin-logo.png" /></a>
</div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".js-navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hireredson</a>

        </div>
      
        <div class="navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">

 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

         <li><a style="width:113px !important" href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('/admin/index');?>">Dashboard</a></li>
            </ul>
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                         <li><a  style="width:113px !important" href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('admin/ListEmployers');?>">Employers</a></li>

             </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           

                <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Manage <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu row">
                       
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Manage</li>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('content/admin');?>">Manage Content</a></li>
                            <li> <a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('admin/ListEmployers');?> ">Manage Employers</a></li>
                            <li>   <a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('admin/listjobs');?> ">Manage Jobs</a></li>
              <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('admin/ManageContact');?>">Manage Enquiry</a></li>
              <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('admin/EmailSettings');?> ">Manage Site Settings</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('admin/profile');?>">Manage Admin Account</a></li>
              <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('admin/ManageFeedback');?>">Manage Feedback</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('admin/corporateRequests');?>">Manage Corporate Requests</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('admin/connectionrequests');?>">Extra Connection Requests</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Products</li>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('site/socialrecruiting');?>">Social Recruiting</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('site/hiringcollabration');?>">Hiring Collaboration</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('site/ats');?>">Automatic Job Posting</a>
                                </li>
                               
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('site/careersite');?>">Careers site Branding</a>
                                </li>
                               
                               
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('site/EmployeeReferral');?>">Employee Referral</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('site/analytics');?>">Analytics</a>
                                </li>
                                 <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('users/register');?>">Signup</a>
                                </li>
                                 <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('users/login');?>">Login</a>
                                </li>
                                  <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('site/Contactus');?>">Contact Us</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">More</li>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('site/TermsOfService');?>">Terms Of Service</a>
                                </li>
                                 <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('site/aboutus');?>">Company</a>
                                </li>
                              
                               
                               
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Account<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu row">
                       
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Account Management</li>
                                 <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl("/admin/profile"); ?>">Edit Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl("admin/logout"); ?>">Log out</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- 
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Jackets</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Easy to customize</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Glyphicons</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Pull Right Elements</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Pants</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Coloured Headers</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Primary Buttons & Default</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Calls to action</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        -->
                        <!-- 
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Accessories</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Default Navbar</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Lovely Fonts</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Responsive Dropdown </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Newsletter</li>
                                <form class="form" role="form">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                                </form>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        -->
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                         <li><a  style="width:113px !important" href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('admin/logout');?>">Logout</a></li>

             </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
    </nav>
</div>













    <?php

} 

    ?>




 
 

    
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
              <!--<div id="content" class="clearfix">--><!-- style="width:988px;" -->
                  <?php echo $content; ?>
                <!--</div>-->
                </div><!--  <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12"> closed  -->
        </div><!--  row-->
        </div><!-- container -->
<!-- Footer -->
 <div class="container">

 <div class="row">


<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
<div class="panel panel-default" style="background-color:#6bc0eb !important;">
  <div class="panel-body">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
       <span class="footertext" style="float:left;color:#fff;">&copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> All Rights Reserved To <?php echo CHtml::encode(Yii::app()->name); ?></span>

  </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-10">

 <span style="float:right">   <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="" ><img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/admin/css/images/logo02.png" width="160" height="24" /></a>
</span>
</div>
 </div>
</div>

</div>
<a href="#" class="scrollToTop"></a>

</div>
</div>

<!-- End Footer -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/admin/js/common.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
$this->breadcrumbs = array(
    'Contents'=> array('admin'),
    $model->title
);
?>
```

Comment: This might not be enough as a reproducible example. Consider including snippets where is shown how are you including bootstrap files.

Comment: Rewrote the question to specify what does the OP need.
Added a relevant tag.
Title improved.

Comment: Updated code please check

Comment: Try inspect the code with firebugs.. could be the boostrap navbar hide the breadcrumbs...

Comment: where you included breadcrumb widget?

Comment: I dont know about that but in old site its working i came  in middle of the project so i dont know  but in old design its working